# I cannot delete a folder with the path C:\Users\Son Nguyen\Desktop\tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz .\

Tags: directory, delete-file, tar.gz

I am having a problem that I cannot delete a folder with the path C:\Users\Son Nguyen\Desktop\tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz .\ . When I delete, open or rename the folder, it gives me an error.

I tried running cmd with administrator privileges using the command C:\Windows\system32>subst d: C:\Users\Son Nguyen\Desktop\tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz .. It shows error: Incorrect number of parameters - Nguyen\Desktop\tar
Method 2, I tried to delete it on 7_Zip File Manage software, but it also failed to delete that folder.

I hope to delete the folder.

Comment: [Delete file containing invalid characters in windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows). Something like `rmdir /s "\\?\c:\Users\Son Nguyen\Desktop\tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz ."` might work. [Superuser](https://superuser.com) is probably a better place to ask about deleting a folder, but check their help center before asking there. How did you create the folder?

Comment: I have created by mkdir So Nguyen in Linux, but when I zip folder I wrote to the command line: tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz ./nguyen_hong_son. That folder Error @NathanMills

Comment: I tried a different command is: rd /s "\\?\c:\Users\Son Nguyen\Desktop\tar -czvf nguyen_hong_son.tar.gz ."  , deleted that folder. 
Thank you so much @NathanMills